# How to stop multiline Regex execution on mismatch

Tags: c#, regex

Take the following sample; it's comprised of a single text string containing multiple lines of data:

```
*
123
1234
12*
1234-123
1234-12*
1234-1234-123
1234-1234-123*
1234-1234-1234
2342-*2340
985*-895-
```

Then I have this Regex that will match valid entries:
`(?m)^\d{0,3}\*$|^\d{4}-\d{0,3}\*$|^\d{4}-\d{4}-\d{0,3}\*$|^\d{4}-\d{4}-\d{4}$`

This Regex does a good job of matching only the valid entries.

The problem I have is that I want to use this as a validator; as only lines 1, 4, 6, 8, and 9 are valid, I would like the Regex to stop execution on the first invalid line and consider the whole thing invalid.

I also tried reversing it, so the Regex would only return the INVALID lines, but that's not really what I want either:
`(?m)^(?!^\d{0,3}\*$|^\d{4}-\d{0,3}\*$|^\d{4}-\d{4}-\d{0,3}\*$|^\d{4}-\d{4}-\d{4}$).*?$`

It does match only the invalid lines, but it still doesn't work as a Validator.

I would like to implement this as a normal Validator control, instead of having to write code for a custom Validator.  It seems like this should be possible, but I haven't managed it yet.

Comment: Just match line by line in a loop and stop if there is no match?

Comment: To implement this as a Validator, it's just a single Regex string that's supposed to do the validation.  If I have to implement a custom validator, I can, but it means both client and server-side coding.  I was hoping the single simple Regex Validator could work.

Comment: I believe you actually want https://regex101.com/r/GqlgXg/2, `^(?:(?:\d{4}-)?\d{0,3}\*|\d{4}-\d{4}-(?:\d{0,3}\*|\d{4}))(?:\r?\n(?:(?:\d{4}-)?\d{0,3}\*|\d{4}-\d{4}-(?:\d{0,3}\*|\d{4})))*\z`

Answer (score 1):

You can just attempt to match the whole input that must contain one or more lines of *valid matches*. For each valid match just provide your sub-patterns like this:

```bash
(?m)\A(?:(?:\d{0,3}\*|\d{4}(?:-\d{4})?-\d{0,3}\*|\d{4}-\d{4}-\d{4})$\n?)+\Z
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/G7ExAf/1)

**RegEx Details:**

- `(?m)`: Enable multiline mode
- `\A`: Start of input
- `(?:`: Start non-capture group #1

  - `(?:`: Start non-capture group #2

    - `\d{0,3}\*`: Match 0 to 3 digits followed by a `*`
    - `|`: OR
    - `\d{4}(?:-\d{4})?-\d{0,3}\*`: Match 4 digits optionally followed by hyphen and 4 digits followed by hyphen and 0 to 3 digits
    - `|`: OR
    - `\d{4}-\d{4}-\d{4}`: Match 3 sets of 4 digits separated by a `-`
  - `)`: End non-capture group #2
  - `$\n?`: Match end of line and an optional line break
- `)+`: End of non-capture group #1. Repeat this group 1+ times
- `\Z`: End of input

Comment: I believe this is EXACTLY what I'm looking for!  So far in testing it looks good.  Thanks, sir!

Comment: @IgnusFast: Did this work out?